# How does a single processor execute the Operating System as well as the user program Simultaneously?

Tags: operating-system

Okay as we know that a single processor can execute one instruction at one time,  which means a single processor can execute either the Operating system's instruction or the user program's instruction at one time.

Now how is it possible that an operating system, and a user program can run at the same time in single processor?

Is cpu assigned to a user program when you open the program and when you close the user program the cpu is assigned back to the Operating system ??

Comment: Ever heard of time slicing?

Comment: They call it time slicing or time sharing. Every millisecond or so, control is passed back and forth to either task, accompanied by a "context switch" (that restores the processor in the same state as when the task was paused). Slices are so short that you don't notice. Personal computers are filled with concurrent tasks (currently 121 of them on my machine.)

Comment: This is off-topic, since the question is not about programming. It should be asked at http://superuser.com/ instead.

Comment: Operating Systems do it via sharing resources such as CPU,RAM,... OS share CPU according to time scheduling. OS do a job every some moments to share CPU that named "SWITCH CONTEXT". There are a lot of description about this on the web.

Comment: But that is the explanation of how to process get executed. My question was about, how a process and the operating system gets executed. Operating system have to manage all the processes by not letting them interfering with each other which mean operating system has be in execution at all the time for protection and other purposes.

Comment: Why is this tagged as C / C++? This has nothing to do with either of these languages.

Comment: @Lundin the question may well be off topic, but I don't think it is on topic for superuser.com either.

Comment: Sounds like you need to read a book on how operating systems work :)

Comment: @user7374714 There is a part of the operating system which manages all the processes, this is all done low-end in hardware where it doesn't have to fight other processes for CPU Time. All other OS processes like UI are split with other processes like Chrome

Comment: @antred because i got it in tag suggestions and operating systems are written mostly in c++ and c

Comment: @Lightness Races That is what i am doing, reading OS Concepts by galvin

Comment: @user7374714 not always...

Comment: High-end single-core CPUs execute tens of instructions in parallel actually. And your definition of OS is way too narrow. An OS provides control of shared resources. But what is a "share resource" can differ a lot. It also does necessarily protect processes (or support concurrent processes at all) against each other. WE had OSs long before there was concurrency.

Comment: @Lundin i got "Operating system" in the suggestions you can check it yourself. Can't you be nice ?? don't you have manners ha ?

Comment: @antred operating systems are mostly written in c++ and c. if you don't know that then you know nothing.

Comment: @user7374714: Then continue reading to the end.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit which book you read ??

Comment: @user7374714: No idea, it was decades ago

Comment: @user7374714 There exists all manner of strange tags on this site, that doesn't matter. Questions about how to program a scheduling operative system would be on-topic, as would questions regarding how to use a certain OS interface such as an API. Questions about how an operative system works is not. Regarding manners, it is considered rude to post on a site before reading about the site scope and posting policies in advance: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @user7374714 Most operating systems may be written in C, but that is not in any way a requirement. It is totally feasible to write an OS without a single line of C code, so again, this question has absolutely NOTHING to do with C or C++.

Comment: @user3344003 This is how they treat people by playing with their question and they do it mostly with new comer. but there are some really good people over here and the reason people ask question is to just get a positive response. btw thanks for your kindness God bless you :)

Comment: There are people who like to run up points here. If they can't answer the question, they vote to close. Unfortunately, I can't really answer the question in a comment, although the answer is not that complicated: exceptions and interrupts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically it is impossible to run two threads on a single processor core at once. However it is possible for the system to pretend to do this by swapping threads on and off the CPU. There are basically two ways to do this. Cooperative and Preemptive multitasking.

In the days of Windows 3, CPUs had a single core (I'm sure some big expensive machines had more but not that normal people got to see). Windows 3 didn't interrupt processes. What happened was processes had to periodically relinquish control to the OS. The OS would then continue the process again at a later time. This model is called cooperative multitasking.

Cooperative multitasking has a bit of an issue though. If a process fails to relinquish control to the OS (normally due to a bug) it can  hog the system's resources and the system needs rebooting. This is why when Windows 95 was released Microsoft switched to a pre-emptive multitasking model.

With pre-emptive multitasking the hardware allows the OS to set an interrupt for a future time (how this is done varies by hardware system). This means that the OS can guarantee to get back on the CPU. When it does this, it stores the state (mainly the CPU registers) of the running thread and then loads a different one. This means that the OS always has control as it does not rely on the processes relinquishing control.

I'm sure other OS used pre-emptive multitasking before Windows 95 but it was Win 95 that really brought it to the mainstream on the PC.

Another issue that can occur is that one process tries to write to the memory used by another process, or a process tries to directly access some hardware without the operating system's permission. When the CPU starts up it is in Real Mode and loads the OS, the OS can then set up certain restrictions and switch the CPU to protected mode before running a process. While in protected mode the CPU will stop the process from accessing memory addresses and hardware that the OS has not allowed, forcing the process to call back to the OS to access these resources.

Comment: Okay i understand what you said but OS has be active all the times so that it will execute its instruction that check if the user programs are interfering with each other while they are been executing.

Comment: On Intel platforms, initially the CPU starts in Real mode and runs the OS. When the OS is ready to start a process it puts the CPU into protected mode. The CPU then stops the process accessing things it shouldn't without calling back into the OS code. This feature of the CPU was introduced with the 286. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode.

Answer (score 2):

### This is called [Preemption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)) or Time Slicing

*In simple terms:*

There are multi-threaded CPU's which can manage multiple threads (instructions)

But even that's not enough. The CPU has to split the workload, it does this by pausing a thread (called an interrupt) and working on another.

An average computer might have over a ***thousand*** threads running, but only 4 CPU Cores (which can only run 4 threads at a time)

### How does it do it?

Some CPU's can only run 4 threads at a time, to manage all the other thousands of threads it must pause the thread and work on another and pause that and work on another, This is called ***Time Slicing*** time is not the only factor, priorities & usage come into play too. CPU's are really fast and can do this in < 1ms

EDIT: The "System Interrupts" is what manages all of this, it's not really a process in sense but this piece of windows is what controls all thread execution

[image]

Comment: But that is the explanation of how to process get executed. My question was about, how a process and the operating system gets executed. Operating system have to manage all the processes by not letting them interfering with each other which mean operating system has be in execution at all the time for protection and other purposes.

Comment: That's what the "System Interrupts" process is exactly for

Comment: @user7374714 And these answers are explaining to you that the OS is not 'running all them time'

Comment: @user7374714 Yes, the OS has it's own processes which also need to be time sliced.

Comment: "This is called Preemption or Time Slicing" - They are not the only way (and preemption is not the same as time-slicing).

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple explanation from : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html:

> So how is concurrency implemented? Parallel work on single core CPUs
>   is an illusion which is somewhat similar to the illusion of moving
>   images in cinema. For processes, the illusion is produced by
>   interrupting the processor's work on one process after a very short
>   time. Then the processor moves on to the next process. In order to
>   switch between processes, the current program counter is saved and the
>   next processor's program counter is loaded.

Comment: But that is the explanation of how to process get executed. My question was about, how a process and the operating system gets executed. Operating system have to manage all the processes by not letting them interfering with each other which mean operating system has be in execution at all the time for protection and other purposes.

Comment: @user7374714 And these answers are explaining to you that the OS is not 'running all them time'